# In PhpMyadmin Count rows issue with mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added below query in phpmyadmin

```
 SELECT id,u_id,count(u_id) As cnt
FROM  `pager` 
WHERE  type = 'profile' group by u_id
```

Query Executed.

I got below output showing (0- 30  results) total 24000 records found

I tried same query in different format

```
SELECT count(u_id) As cnt,id,u_id
FROM  `pager` 
WHERE  type = 'profile' group by u_id
```

Query Executed.
I got below Query Executed Successfully.SHowing just 30 records , No Pagination dropdown.I can't click id and u_id field heading to sort..Someone please help what is the issue..I think both query should execute 24000 records..Please advise

Answer (score 3):

PhpMyAdmin display default results as per it's settings which you can change from **Number of rows : dropdown** value in the interface.

If you need to display all your result, then you must add **limit** clause in your query to display all records

```
SELECT id,u_id,count(u_id) As cnt
FROM  `pager` 
WHERE  type = 'profile' group by u_id
LIMIT 0, 999999
```

Otherwise, it will display 30 resuts (or whatever default PhpMyAdmin settings)

**NOTE:** To sort out the results, add **Order by** clause in your query then the query would look like following:

```
SELECT id,u_id,count(u_id) As cnt
FROM  `pager` 
WHERE  type = 'profile' group by u_id
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 0, 999999
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply.But I have one more question .Why pagination dropdown not shown for second query

Comment: It could be a bug in PhpMyAdmin as it is not related to any data problem issue. You will have all your data.